# How to format images for web file transfer

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, validation, png, axios

I am trying to write an app which sends images from a phone to an Amazon S3 bucket.  Currently I am testing the app with png files.  Everything seems to work accept the images are not being formatted properly for web transfer.  I have tried a number of different things but I am out of ideas.

I am uploading my image like this:

```
onChange = () => {
    let newfile = this.refs.file.files[0];
    let reader = new FileReader();
    let url = reader.readAsDataURL(newfile);
    reader.onloadend = () => {
        this.setState({
            ...this.state,
            openModal: true,
            imgSrc : [reader.result],
            imageType: newfile.type,
        })
    }
}
```

I know this image upload works because I am able to display my picture with

```
<img src={this.state.imgSrc} />
```

console logging imgSrc gives me a string that continues for 26,000 characters `"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAASQAAAEjCAYAAACb/HxUAAAA..."`

I am making a put request to my Amazon S3 bucket but I cannot get the image to appear!

```
var headers= {
                  'Content-Type': this.state.imageType,
                };
return axios.put(signedUrl, this.state.imgSrc, {headers:headers})
```

When I console log the response from Amazon it looks like this.

```
{data: "", status: 200, statusText: "OK", headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}
config:
adapter: ƒ xhrAdapter(config)
data: "["data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAS"
headers: {Accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*", Content-Type: "image/png"}
maxContentLength: -1
method: "put"
timeout: 0
transformRequest: {0: ƒ}
transformResponse: {0: ƒ}
url: "https://bucket.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/1_1553270707390?Content-Type=image%2Fpng&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-
validateStatus: ƒ validateStatus(status)
xsrfCookieName: "XSRF-TOKEN"
xsrfHeaderName: "X-XSRF-TOKEN"
__proto__: Object
data: ""
headers: {}
request: XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: ƒ, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, …}
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: Woah, you might need to fuzz out your URL in this post I think they even include AWS creds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be sending the actual file (i.e. `newfile`) and not the `data:` URL you converted it to with `readAsDataURL`.